# WatchOS SwiftUI animation view resizing parent

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, watchos

I have a simple animation on a circle inside a swiftUI view, however when i use the view in its parent, it resizes the parent view during animation. if I copy the same animation directly into the parent's view it works as expected.

my animation view is:

```
struct Spinner: View{

@State private var spin = false

var body: some View {
    Image(systemName: "arrow.2.circlepath")
        .resizable()
        .frame(width: 50, height: 40)
        .rotationEffect(
            .degrees(spin ? 360: 0)
        )
        .animation(
            Animation.linear(duration: 1).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)
        )
        .onAppear(){
            self.spin.toggle()
        }

    }
}
```

[image: Animation Inside Child View Spinner():]

Inside Scroll View:

```
 ScrollView {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello World").bold()            
            Button(action: {}){
                Spinner()
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: Animation directly in View]

however inside a view works:

Directly in View

```
 ScrollView {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello World").bold()            
            Button(action: {}){
                Image(systemName: "arrow.2.circlepath")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 50, height: 40)
                .rotationEffect(
                     .degrees(spin ? 360: 0)
                )
                .animation(
                      Animation.linear(duration: 1).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)
                )
                .onAppear(){
                    self.spin.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: if dont mind can add some sample code to understand more

Comment: updated @HarshalBhavsar

Comment: Also can the second image be also gif?

Comment: done @HarshalBhavsar

Comment: Sorry for delayed reply

Answer (score 0):

I tried both of your block of code

**Case 1**

```swift
struct Spinner: View{

    @State private var spin = false

    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: "arrow.2.circlepath")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 50, height: 40)
            .rotationEffect(
                .degrees(spin ? 360: 0)
        )
            .animation(
                Animation.linear(duration: 1).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)
        )
            .onAppear(){
                self.spin.toggle()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                Text("Hello World").bold()
                Text("Hello World").bold()
                Text("Hello World").bold()
                Text("Hello World").bold()
                Button(action: {}){
                    Spinner()
                }
                Text("Hello World").bold()
                Text("Hello World").bold()
                Text("Hello World").bold()
                Text("Hello World").bold()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Case 2**

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var spin = false

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                Text("Hello World").bold()
                Text("Hello World").bold()
                Text("Hello World").bold()
                Text("Hello World").bold()
                Button(action: {}){
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.2.circlepath")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 50, height: 40)
                        .rotationEffect(
                            .degrees(spin ? 360: 0)
                    )
                        .animation(
                            Animation.linear(duration: 1).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)
                    )
                        .onAppear(){
                            self.spin.toggle()
                    }
                }
                Text("Hello World").bold()
                Text("Hello World").bold()
                Text("Hello World").bold()
                Text("Hello World").bold()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE: I added some extra labels to make the content scrollable**

Both of the above gives the same results i think your previous gif's were not form the recent code.

Please try once again and see if works or not. If the code you added in example is correct should work

[image: Result of Case 1 and 2]